# StaleElementReferenceException in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

```
wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-transfer-container"]/div/div/form/button[1]')
    )
)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-transfer-container"]/div/div/form/button[1]').click()
```

Here is my code in which I am trying to click a button with Selenium. I am waiting for the button to be clickable but when I actually try to click the button I get a stale element error. Any help would be much appreciated as I have tried several different solutions from existing stack overflow posts with no luck!

UPDATE:

this worked

```
    stale = True

    while stale:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id="react-transfer-container"]/div/div/form/button[1]'
            ).click()
            stale = False
        except:
            stale = True
```

Comment: what happens in UI before you click it is there any changes happening ?

Comment: @PDHide there aren't any changes that I can see, I just load the page and attempt to click the button. What is especially confusing to me is that the wait executes with no error so the element is found to be clickable, but then immediately after, the actual click fails.

Comment: Stale element doesn't have much to do with wait if any asynchronous actions happens in background

Comment: Do you have link to that ? Page

Comment: @PDHide it's actually the final page for sending a PayPal transaction (trying to click the "send money" button...not sure if you will be able to take a look at that haha